# Fonts icons not showing properly even if I route them correctly

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

Here is my problem, I downloaded the fontawesome files into my project folder because the place where I pretend to implement my project has proxy restrictions so most of the websites and CDNs are restircted, the problem I'm experiencing is that I can´t get my Icons displayed properly, I only get theese square symbols whereever I use theese icons on a file stored on a route different from my project root folder. Here you have my html code and some pictures to prove my point.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-    scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../icons/fawe/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <header class="row bg-dark align-items-center">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="../../imagenes/pdvsa.svg" width="140px" height="40px">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-auto">
        <p class="acron-sistema">SAGEPCYS</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <p class="titulo-sistema">Sistema Automatizado de Gestión a la Plataforma de Control y Seguridad.</p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section class="row">
      <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-dark sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                <span class="far fa-file-alt"></span> Cargar Documentos
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span data-feather="file"></span> Orders
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span> Products
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span data-feather="users"></span> Customers
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span> Reports
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                <span data-feather="layers"></span> Integrations
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </section>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The important part of this code is where I link the icon fonts stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../icons/fawe/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
```

And here where I call the icon setting the class attribute as documentation indicates.

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="#">
  <span class="far fa-file-alt"></span> Cargar Documentos
</a>
```

Here are the images

[image]

[image]

I hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added the content of the webfonts folder
[image: Webfonts folder]

Comment: in addition to downloading the .css file you will also have to download the Fonts folder which the CDN does when you use it

Comment: @happymacarts the fonts files are on the webfonts folder which you can see at the end of the project folder tree pictures.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your console? Missing file xyz...?

Comment: @happymacarts not at all, the console is also clean as hell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to display icons correctly, aparently the icons can only be displayed on the root folder and one level below the root, of course depending on where you place your icons on your project... This is the best aproach to a solution that I could find... Hope it helps somebody...

Answer (score 1):

Fontawesome requires a link to the fonts folder as well

if you visit [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css)  there are very detailed instructions on using the library without the cdn

view the **Download, Customize, and Serve Yourself** section

> 1. **Grab & move the CSS and web fonts into your project** The fontawesome-all.css contains the core styling plus all the visual
>      styles that you'll need when using Font Awesome. The webfonts folder
>      contains all of the typeface files that the above CSS references and
>      depends on.
>
>    Copy the entire webfonts folder and the fontawesome-all.css into your
>      project's static assets directory (or where ever you prefer to keep
>      front end assets or vendor stuff). Make sure you remember the path for
>      referencing.
> 2. **Reference the CSS** Add a reference to the fontawesome-all.css styling file into the  of each template or page that you want to
>      use Font Awesome on. Pay attention to the pathing of your project and
>      where you moved the files to in the previous step.
> 3. **Place icons in your UI's markup** as you normally would

**Version 5**

```
<i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> --> for solid icons
<i class="far fa-file-alt"></i> --> for regular icons
<i class="fal fa-file-alt"></i> --> for light icons (pro only)
```

**Version 4**

```
<i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i>
```

Comment: The webfonts folder is also on the project folder at the same level of the css folder where the css files are, it seems to be some kind of trouble with the routes since I can see the icons displayed correctly on my login page, since it's located at the root project folder..

Comment: are these in your "public" folder? all your css should be accessible at the root level outside of any framework routing or AUTH

Comment: Does all your other CS load fine?

Comment: which version of fontawesome are you using?

Comment: Yes all my other CSS files are loading properly, well I'm actually using bootstrap as Front-End framework, but nothing else, and Bootstrap is loading fine, and the classes of the icons from fontawesome changed from version 4 to version 5, actually I'm copying and pasting the classes directly from the cheashet on FA webpage..

Comment: should the class be `fas fa-file-alt` ? NOT "far"

Comment: Already tried with fas, fab, fa, far classes and no result..mate

Comment: what files are in your webfonts folder? you can replace the image with that folder expanded if you want. It really sounds like the fonts are not being loaded. Is this on a local testing server or is it hosted now?

Comment: I added the webfonts folder picture to the post, I'm testing on a local server right now..

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your paths or the file structure. my only thought is that because it is out of the "root" folder your local web server may have some permission issues of some type. do you have a live server you can load this to to test?

Comment: On live preview doesnt even show the squares where the icons are suppossed to be.. anyways, I'll continue working and let the icons problem to another day, Thank you mate..!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had wrongly set up a cache plugin at https://carmenhalffter.com/ by compressing, combining and preloading the font awesome file. After I restored the settings, it was working again.